# Issue tracking only see issues you created

Tags: list, issue-tracking

Is it possible to make an issue tracking list only allow users to see the issues they have created? Normally under list settings I would do this under Advanced Settings but that option does not seem to be there.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new view and set the filter Created By equals [Me]. Set that as the default view.

Comment: Could a user not still see any issues if they manipulate the URL to have a differnt ticket id?

Comment: Ooo... I don't think that's doable, I once wrote a custom feature to lay on top of the issue list which had custom pages and web parts and I handled all of the permission trimming in my code. What a pain, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint hides that section for:

1) Document Library
2) List created from issues list template
3) External lists.

Your options:

1) Set `ReadSecurity = 2` of your issues list programatically. I have not tried it but this is what SharePoint does behind the scene if that section was available in advanced settings page. Also set `SPList.WriteSecurity` as per your need. [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist_members.aspx) has more information on the ReadSecurity and WriteSecurity

2) Start with custom issues list instead of using Issues list template

Comment: Not seen ReadSecurity before - interesting! If OP doesn't want to do this programatically then this tool may help set - http://spm.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this by customizing the default Public list view?  You would set a Filter on the public view to show only "[Me]".

Answer (score 0):

You can also create list event receiver for the purpose. When a issue item is created, detach its permission inheritance, remove all users and assign read permission only to the user for the item.